# MYSQL INSERT foreach in table

Tags: php, mysql

I have following table in mysql icalproperty

ipid propertid name roomtypename roomtypecode
1    1         test
2    2         test
3    3         test2

I want to insert values into roomtype and roomtypecode
My code is :

```
        foreach($rtypes1 as $roomtype)      
        {
            $sSQL = sprintf(

            "INSERT INTO icalproperty

            (roomtypename, roomtypecode)

            VALUES ('%s','%s'),

            WHERE property_id=".$villa['hotelid']."
            ",

            mysql_real_escape_string($roomtype['roomtypedesc']),
            mysql_real_escape_string($roomtype['roomcode'])
            );
        }
        $rResult = mysql_query($sSQL);

        if(mysql_errno() > 0){
            printf(
                '<h4 style="color: red;">Query Error:</h4>
                <p>(%s) - %s</p>
                <p>Query: %s</p>
                <hr />',
                mysql_errno(),
                mysql_error(),
                $sSQL
                );
        }
```

I have following error message

Query Error:

(1064) - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE property_id=842' at line 7

Query: INSERT INTO icalproperty (roomtypename, roomtypecode) VALUES ('Villa Charmony','2825'), WHERE property_id=842

Any solution?

Comment: I would suggest using PDO, `mysql_` is on the outs, and not usable in PHP7+

Comment: That said the problem is that last `,` here `VALUES ('%s','%s'),` remove that.  `INSERT INTO icalproperty (roomtypename, roomtypecode)VALUES('%s','%s') WHERE ...`

Comment: you're probably looking for [update statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)